# WooCommerce: Reorder tabs without showing empty tabs

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to reorder the tabs on the product page.
To do this, I'm using the following code:

```
function reorder_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
    $tabs['gm_fic_ingredients']['priority'] = 10;
    $tabs['gm_fic_nutritional_values']['priority'] = 30;
    $tabs['gm_fic_allergens']['priority'] = 20;
    $tabs['additional_information']['priority'] = 100;
    return $tabs;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'reorder_product_tabs', 98 );
```

It works well if every tab has some content.
But if the tab is empty, it will show as empty element without a title or content. Only the markup.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Because you use tabs that are not standard in WooCommerce, this is difficult to test. Use  `echo '<pre>', print_r($tabs, 1), '</pre>';` as the first code line in your callback function, 
this will give you more information about the tabs. Then you could use something like `if ( empty( $tabs['content'] )`.

Comment: @7uc1f3r Sorry but `$tabs['content']` doesn't exist as `$tabs[''callback']` is the name of the function that is called to display the content…

Comment: As you are have 3 custom tabs and you don't give any details on them, nobody is going to be able to guess what they are for and how to hide them when there is no content…

Comment: These tabs are part of the GermanMarket plugin. I will ask their support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now using the following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'product_tabs_additional_information_priority', 98 );
function product_tabs_additional_information_priority( $tabs ) {
    global $product;
    $tabs['additional_information']['priority'] = '100';

    return $tabs;
}
```

It changes only the priority of one single tab and has no impact of tabs without content.